# How is this limit being solved? I can't grasp it

Tags: limits, fractions, irrational-numbers

I am going over limits for my finals as I notice this example in my schoolbook discribing limits of the undefined form $0\over0$ in the shape of an irrational fraction.

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} {\sqrt[3]{x}-1\over\sqrt{2x-1}-1} = {0\over0} = \lim\limits_{x \to 1} {(\sqrt[3]{x}-1)(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1)(\sqrt{2x-1}+1)\over(\sqrt{2x-1}-1)(\sqrt{2x-1}+1)(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1)}$$

I really don't get what is going on here. I know that you are supposed to multiply both the nominator and the denominator by the added value of either. But it appears that here it has been mutliplied by both? And where does this term $(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1)$ come from?

There is no worked out example, except for the solution after this which is $1\over3$ but thats it.

Could anyone please explain this to me? I would be really gratefull!
Also sorry if I didn't use the correct terms here and there, not a native english speaker.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers, Michiel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: $(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=a^3-b^3$ and $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$.

Comment: This one completely answers the question. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I know these rules but I seem to fail at placing them into context here..

Comment: If your $0/0$ limit is the ratio of two polynomials, then we know that you can factor out $x-1$ from both and hopefully get a ratio of non-vanishing polynomials. But if roots are present that scheme does not work: those tricks allow you then to transform the irrational expressions at numerator and denominator into vanishing polynomials.

Comment: Wow, after searching for the solution so long on 1 example I just couldn't understand it. Tried a few other examples and this suddenly became very clear. I can't believe it took me this long to get it. Thank you!! :D

Answer (score 2):

$${\sqrt[3]{x}-1\over\sqrt{2x-1}-1} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{\sqrt{2x-1}-1}\cdot \frac{(\sqrt{2x-1}+1)\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1\right)}{(\sqrt{2x-1}+1)\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1\right)}$$

$$=\frac{\left((\sqrt[3]{x}-1)\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1\right)\right)(\sqrt{2x-1}+1)}{\left((\sqrt{2x-1})^2-1^2\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1\right)}$$

$$=\frac{(x-1)(\sqrt{2x-1}+1)}{2(x-1)\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1\right)}=\frac{\sqrt{2x-1}+1}{2\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1\right)}$$

$$\stackrel{x\to 1}\to \frac{\sqrt{2(1)-1}+1}{2\left(\sqrt[3]{1^2}+\sqrt[3]{1}+1\right)}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Wow thanks! This is everything I needed! Except I still fail to see where $(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1)$ comes from? I see that this $(\sqrt{2x-1}+1)$ is the opposite but I don't get the other term..

Comment: @TheAlPaca02 $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a}{b}\cdot \frac{c}{c}$ for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$, $bc\neq 0$. Let $a=\sqrt[3]{x}-1$, $b=\sqrt{2x-1}-1$, $c=(\sqrt{2x-1}+1)\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1\right)$. After that I applied Aretino's answer formulas.

Comment: I'm so sorry but I still don't understand where you are getting the value for C ..

Comment: Yes I get that, but if $c\over c$ has to = 1 , why choose exactly those values?

Answer (score 0):

Where does $\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1$ comes from? The identity you can use is
$$
a^3-1=(a-1)(a^2+a+1)
$$
with $a=\sqrt[3]{x}$; so, multipliying numerator and denominator by $\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1$ you get rid of part of the indetermination, together with the fact that, multiplying numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{2x-1}+1$ the denominator becomes $(2x-1)-1=2(x-1)$, so the factors $x-1$ cancel each other.

Let me show a different way for computing the limit. With a bit of experience, you can split this into
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{x-1}
\cdot
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{2x-1}-1}
$$
(provided both limits exist, and this is where experience gets in).

The first limit can be done by a simple substitution, $x=t^3$:
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{x-1}=
\lim_{t\to1}\frac{t-1}{t^3-1}=
\lim_{t\to1}\frac{1}{t^2+t+1}=\frac{1}{3}
$$
Similarly, for the second limit you can set $\sqrt{2x-1}-1=t$, so $2x-1=t^2+2t+1$, $x=(t^2+2t+2)/2$ and $x-1=(t^2+2t)/2$; therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{2x-1}-1}=
\frac{1}{2}\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t^2+2t}{t}=
\frac{1}{2}\lim_{t\to0}(t+2)=1
$$

To do it with Taylor expansions, substitute $x=t+1$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+t}-1}{\sqrt{1+2t}-1}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1+\frac{1}{3}t+o(t)-1}{1+\frac{1}{2}(2t)-1}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{3}t+o(t)}{t+o(t)}=\frac{1}{3}
$$

Comment: Thanks for such a complete answer! I understand now :D. Because of my inexperience I am going to stick to the regular way of solving this for now, but this definitely helped me understand!